# bower install hanging with no error

Tags: bower, bower-install

Though I have found a few people having similar problems as mine, nothing seemed to work so far, and I'm a bit short of information, so here is the problem:

On my local machine, `bower install` runs perfectly fine. But on the jenkins server, the same operation seems to "hang" in the middle of the installation of `jquery-ui-sortable` for some reason. I have no error message, and I could very well leave my terminal open for quite some time without having any error on screen.

It was working very fine until recently, when I added a new dependency (from our private bower repository, let's call it `core`). If I comment out that dependency, it runs perfectly fine, which I don't quite understand since the error is on `jquery-ui-sortable` and not on `core`.

I have tried upgrading bower to the latest stable release and clearing the cache with no success. My main problem is that I can't find a way to get any meaningful information, the `--verbose` flag doesn't do anything.

I know this is hardly enough information to solve the issue, so that's why I would gladly appreciate any tip on how to debug this situation.

In advance, thank you.

- bower version: 1.3.12
- npm version: 1.4.9
- Running on CentOS

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, solved it by downgrading bower. v1.3.12 did not work and the projects package.json explicitly asked for v1.3.3.

To debug I added versoning to all the commands used when calling from jenkins.
I then saw it used the globals and not the one installed by npm.

Also make sure $PATH lists you correct bower